# mvc4 htmlhelper extension to store block of html for later output in same file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Ok, here's what I'm trying to do... given this razor code

```
@using(Html.WriteLater())
{
    output line one
}
actual first line
@using(Html.WriteLater())
{
    output line two
}
actual second line

@HTML.WriteNow();
```

I want this output:

```
actual first line
actual second line
output line one
output line two
```

There are times when it is nice to logically group  blocks of code together in the view, but the final output needs to be organized differently.  I've tried ataching a different ViewContext in my helper logic but it doesn't work:

```
public static WriteLaterContainer WriteLater( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper )
{
    ViewContext vc = new ViewContext();
    return new WriteLaterContainer( vc );
}
```

Comment: obviously, my WriteLater function is greatly simplified here.  I was hoping to create a new viewcontext with it's own textwriter and have that textwriter capture the contents of the using block that followed the function call... but that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why would you want to reinvent wheels instead of using standard approaches such as partials, sections, helpers, ... but I guess you probably have some reasons. So not exactly the syntax you have shown but you could achieve similar results by using a conjunction of 2 helpers:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private const string QueueKey = "_output_queue_";
    public static IHtmlString WriteLater(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> action)
    {
        var queue = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[QueueKey] as Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>;
        if (queue == null)
        {
            queue = new Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>();
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[QueueKey] = queue;
        }
        queue.Enqueue(action);

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static IHtmlString WriteNow(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var queue = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[QueueKey] as Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>;
        if (queue == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var writer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;
        foreach (var item in queue)
        {
            item(null).WriteTo(writer);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

that could be used like this:

```
@Html.WriteLater(@<div>output line one</div>)
<div>actual first line</div>
@Html.WriteLater(@<div>output line two</div>)
<div>actual second line</div>
@Html.WriteNow()
```

and the output will be the expected one:

```
actual first line
actual second line
output line one
output line two
```